# Get row and cell value from dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the row and cell from a dynamically generated table onClick function. I am getting undefined currently.

```
xmlTitles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
                document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = "Playlist (" + xmlTitles.length + " videos)";
                document.getElementById('table').cellSpacing = "5px";
                for (var i = 0; i < xmlTitles.length; i++)
                {
                    tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    tr.style.height = "100px";
                    titles[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    image[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    filename[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filename")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    td2 = document.createElement('td');
                    var _image = iPath + image[i];
                    td2.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:callVideo(this);'><img src='" + _image + "'/></a>";
                    td2.style.verticalAlign = "top";
                    tr.appendChild(td2);
                    td1 = document.createElement('td');
                    var _title = titles[i];
                    td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_title));
                    td1.style.verticalAlign = "top";
                    td1.style.width = "200px";
                    td1.style.height = "100px";
                    td1.style.color = "#0000ff";
                    td1.style.fontFamily = "arial";
                    tr.appendChild(td1);
                    document.getElementById('table').appendChild(tr);
                }
            }
```

This is the function called:

```
function callVideo(x)
            {
                console.log("Cell index: " + x.cellIndex);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: in your code, `this` which is sent to the `callVideo` function will refer to the anchor element, not to the table cell.

Comment: *this* is *window*, to make it the anchor, it should be ```<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callVideo(this)"></a>```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are having is the context of your callVideo function. When you build up the dynamic table, you create an anchor tag inside td2 and then put the event handler on the a tags href, passing in this. I would suspect, that x in callVideo is not the TD element at all, but the anchor tag (a tag) and since a tags have no cellIndex, it will be undefined. Add a console.log(x) into callVideo and establish exactly what x is. If I am correct, the x.parentNode should get you the TD tag

```
function callVideo(x)
{
    console.log(x); //Establish what x is
    console.log("Cell index: " + x.parentNode.cellIndex);
}
```

**EDIT**
In response to comment.

OK so you're having issues establishing the context of the eventHandler. I would change the way you are setting it up, as it not really best practice. An `<a>` is an anchor/link, and running a function on click is changing its default behaviour, which means you have it add things like javascript(void) or href="#" and return false or e.preventDefault() just to stop it from doing what is suppose to do. All not best practice. Why not just add a click handler to the img, or to the whole cell. eg (I removed the style stuff for clarity, I think that should be in CSS not Javascript too by the way)

```
xmlTitles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = "Playlist (" + xmlTitles.length + " videos)";
document.getElementById('table').cellSpacing = "5px";
for (var i = 0; i < xmlTitles.length; i++)
{
    tr = document.createElement('tr');  
    titles[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    image[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    filename[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filename")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    td2 = document.createElement('td');
    //change here
    var imgEle = document.createElement('img')
    imgEle.src = iPath + image[i];
    imgEle.addEventListener('click', callVideo);
    td2.appendChild(imgEle);

    tr.appendChild(td2);
    td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var _title = titles[i];
    td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_title));
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    document.getElementById('table').appendChild(tr);
}

function callVideo()
{
    //'this' will be the img itself
    //so this.parentNode will be the cell (TD)
    console.log(this.parentNode.cellIndex);
    //this.parentNode.parentNode will be the row (TR)
    console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
}
```

OH and by the way, all the cells will return 0 as that is their index, remember Javascript indexes start from 0 (i.e. 0 is the first one, 1 is the second one etc). So to be honest, I'm not sure why you need the cellIndex, as it will always be 0 (i.e. the first cell) as you already know its in the first cell, because your code created it. Although if this is just a snippet from larger code, and you have images in other cells then it would make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked to a point. x is returning javascript:void(0) and all the cells are returning 0. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I will try it, this explanation makes sense, I'll let you know the results. And yes this is only part, there are many image cells, each launches a different video so it is important to know the row and cell that is clicked to launch the correct video, Thanks for your time...

Comment: or, maybe you should consider adding click event handler on the "#table", so let it handle the click events in its containing elements (aka. event delegation). Then in your event handler, you need to test if eventArg.target is the interested table cell.

Answer (score 0):

two changes need to make, given your dynamic generation of DOM is correct.

1. change `<a href="javascript:callVideo(this)">...</a>` to `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callVideo(this)">...</a>`, to make it an *event handler*. Otherwise because the execution of the function via **href** is in *global* context, **this** will be effectively the *global* object which is **window**. Therefore your function will receive **window** as its parameter which is wrong
2. change the body of your `callVideo` function to OJay's solution

   > ```
   > function callVideo(x)
   > {
   >    console.log(x); //Establish what x is
   >    console.log("Cell index: " + x.parentNode.cellIndex);
   > }
   > ```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked to a point. x is returning javascript:void(0) and all the cells are returning 0. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: if I replace the 0 in the javasript:void(0) with "+td2+" , x returns as htmltabledatacellelement but all the cells still show an index of 0.